# Double integral of $\ln(x^2+y^2+1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm have some trouble with this one, maybe someone can help.

Domain: (1 $\leq$ $x^2 + y^2 $ $\leq$ 2)

$$\iint_D \ln(1+x^2 + y^2)dxdy$$

I have a hard time getting the right answer:    $\pi( ln(27/4)-1)$.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You can parametrize the domain by $x(r,t)=r\cos t,y(r,t)=r\sin t$, $(r,t)\in [1,2]\times [0,2\pi)$.

This is known to have Jacobian $r$, so you get $$\iint_D \log(1+x^2+y^2)dxdy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^{\sqrt 2} \log(1+r^2)rdrdt=2\pi\int_1^{\sqrt 2}\log(1+r^2)rdr$$

Comment: note that the upper bound should be $\sqrt{2}$ and not $2$ - easy enough mistake to make.

Comment: @ChrisK True. ${}$